# how to speed up ggwithinplot for large dataset?

Tags: r, performance, r-package

**The problem**

I am using ggwithinplot in ggstatsplot to plot 1755 data points and it turns out to be very slow.

I confirmed this problem by testing the consumed time to plot different number of data points:

1.N=120, 5.576425 secs.

2.N=360, 11.90681 secs.

3.N=1755, 6.699168 **mins** but not secs.

**What I've tried**

1. I transformed the data.frame into data.table. It helped.
2. I set point.path = FALSE in ggwithinplot. It helped.
3. I set nboot=1 in ggwithinplot to reduce the time to calculate the CI of the effect size. It helped.

**Code**

```
  ggwithinstats(long_general_disBU_dt, x = condition, y = disBU,
                         point.path = FALSE,
                         mean.ci = TRUE,
                         pairwise.comparisons = TRUE,
                         pairwise.annotation = "asterisk",
                         pairwise.display = "s",
                         effsize.type = 'partial_eta',
                         p.adjust.method = "fdr",
                         ggtheme = theme_classic(),
                         palette = "Darjeeling2",
                         package = "wesanderson",
                         ggstatsplot.layer = FALSE,
                         bf.message= FALSE,
                         nboot=1,
                         xlab = "targets", 
                         ylab = "general_disBU_dt",
                         title = "general disBU across 20 news")
```

**session info:**

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 15063)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936  LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936 LC_NUMERIC=C                              
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] splines   stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] reshape_0.8.8      gginnards_0.0.3    VGAM_1.1-2         parameters_0.6.0   nnet_7.3-13        openxlsx_4.1.4    
 [7] summarytools_0.9.6 ggcorrplot_0.1.3   bruceR_0.4.0       performance_0.4.4  lubridate_1.7.4    psych_1.9.12.31   
[13] data.table_1.12.8  rio_0.5.16         ggstatsplot_0.3.1  forcats_0.5.0      stringr_1.4.0      dplyr_0.8.5       
[19] purrr_0.3.3        readr_1.3.1        tidyr_1.0.2        tibble_2.1.3       ggplot2_3.3.0      tidyverse_1.3.0   
[25] drawMap_0.1.0     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] estimability_1.3          GGally_1.4.0              lavaan_0.6-5              coda_0.19-3              
  [5] acepack_1.4.1             knitr_1.28                multcomp_1.4-12           rpart_4.1-15             
  [9] inline_0.3.15             generics_0.0.2            callr_3.4.2               cowplot_1.0.0            
 [13] TH.data_1.0-10            xml2_1.2.5                httpuv_1.5.2              StanHeaders_2.21.0-1     
 [17] assertthat_0.2.1          d3Network_0.5.2.1         WRS2_1.0-0                xfun_0.12                
 [21] hms_0.5.3                 promises_1.1.0            fansi_0.4.1               dbplyr_1.4.2             
 [25] readxl_1.3.1              igraph_1.2.4.2            htmlwidgets_1.5.1         DBI_1.1.0                
 [29] Rsolnp_1.16               paletteer_1.1.0           rcompanion_2.3.25         backports_1.1.5          
 [33] pbivnorm_0.6.0            insight_0.8.2             rapportools_1.0           libcoin_1.0-5            
 [37] jmvcore_1.2.5             vctrs_0.2.4               sjlabelled_1.1.3          abind_1.4-5              
 [41] withr_2.1.2               pryr_0.1.4                metaBMA_0.6.2             checkmate_2.0.0          
 [45] bdsmatrix_1.3-4           emmeans_1.4.5             fdrtool_1.2.15            prettyunits_1.1.1        
 [49] fastGHQuad_1.0            mnormt_1.5-6              cluster_2.1.0             mi_1.0                   
 [53] crayon_1.3.4              pkgconfig_2.0.3           nlme_3.1-145              statsExpressions_0.3.1   
 [57] palr_0.2.0                pals_1.6                  rlang_0.4.5               lifecycle_0.2.0          
 [61] miniUI_0.1.1.1            groupedstats_0.2.0        skimr_2.1                 LaplacesDemon_16.1.4     
 [65] MatrixModels_0.4-1        sandwich_2.5-1            kutils_1.69               EMT_1.1                  
 [69] modelr_0.1.6              dichromat_2.0-0           tcltk_3.6.3               cellranger_1.1.0         
 [73] matrixStats_0.56.0        broomExtra_2.5.0          lmtest_0.9-37             Matrix_1.2-18            
 [77] regsem_1.5.2              loo_2.2.0                 mc2d_0.1-18               carData_3.0-3            
 [81] boot_1.3-24               zoo_1.8-7                 reprex_0.3.0              base64enc_0.1-3          
 [85] whisker_0.4               processx_3.4.2            png_0.1-7                 viridisLite_0.3.0        
 [89] rjson_0.2.20              oompaBase_3.2.9           pander_0.6.3              ggExtra_0.9              
 [93] afex_0.26-0               multcompView_0.1-8        coin_1.3-1                arm_1.10-1               
 [97] jpeg_0.1-8.1              rockchalk_1.8.144         ggsignif_0.6.0            scales_1.1.0             
[101] magrittr_1.5              plyr_1.8.6                compiler_3.6.3            rstantools_2.0.0         
[105] bbmle_1.0.23.1            RColorBrewer_1.1-2        lme4_1.1-21               cli_2.0.2                
[109] lmerTest_3.1-1            pbapply_1.4-2             ps_1.3.2                  TMB_1.7.16               
[113] Brobdingnag_1.2-6         htmlTable_1.13.3          Formula_1.2-3             MASS_7.3-51.5            
[117] mgcv_1.8-31               tidyselect_1.0.0          stringi_1.4.6             lisrelToR_0.1.4          
[121] sem_3.1-9                 jtools_2.0.2              OpenMx_2.17.3             latticeExtra_0.6-29      
[125] ggrepel_0.8.2             bridgesampling_1.0-0      grid_3.6.3                tools_3.6.3              
[129] parallel_3.6.3            matrixcalc_1.0-3          rstudioapi_0.11           foreign_0.8-76           
[133] gridExtra_2.3             ipmisc_1.2.0              pairwiseComparisons_0.2.5 BDgraph_2.62             
[137] digest_0.6.25             shiny_1.4.0.2             nortest_1.0-4             jmv_1.2.5                
[141] Rcpp_1.0.3                car_3.0-7                 broom_0.5.5               metafor_2.1-0            
[145] ez_4.4-0                  BayesFactor_0.9.12-4.2    metaplus_0.7-11           later_1.0.0              
[149] httr_1.4.1                effectsize_0.2.0          sjstats_0.17.9            colorspace_1.4-1         
[153] rvest_0.3.5               XML_3.99-0.3              fs_1.3.2                  truncnorm_1.0-8          
[157] rematch2_2.1.0            expm_0.999-4              mapproj_1.2.7             jcolors_0.0.4            
[161] MuMIn_1.43.15             xtable_1.8-4              jsonlite_1.6.1            nloptr_1.2.2.1           
[165] corpcor_1.6.9             rstan_2.19.3              glasso_1.11               zeallot_0.1.0            
[169] modeltools_0.2-23         scico_1.1.0               R6_2.4.1                  Hmisc_4.3-1              
[173] broom.mixed_0.2.4         pillar_1.4.3              htmltools_0.4.0           mime_0.9                 
[177] glue_1.3.2                fastmap_1.0.1             minqa_1.2.4               codetools_0.2-16         
[181] maps_3.3.0                pkgbuild_1.0.6            mvtnorm_1.1-0             lattice_0.20-40          
[185] numDeriv_2016.8-1.1       huge_1.3.4                curl_4.3                  DescTools_0.99.34        
[189] gtools_3.8.1              magick_2.3                logspline_2.1.15          zip_2.0.4                
[193] survival_3.1-11           qgraph_1.6.5              repr_1.1.0                munsell_0.5.0            
[197] semPlot_1.1.2             sjmisc_2.8.3              haven_2.2.0               reshape2_1.4.3           
[201] gtable_0.3.0              bayestestR_0.5.2
```

Is there anything I can do to speed up the ggwithinplot function?

Comment: How long does this computation take if you set `pairwise.comparisons = FALSE`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Faster. 6.37717 mins. But I do need this function. Any new ideas about the reason why it's so time-consuming?

Comment: The most time-consuming part of the process is creating the subtitle with statistical details, and especially running bootstrapping to compute confidence intervals for the effect size measure. If you just want to visualize the data, set `results.subtitle = FALSE` and that will speed up the process.

Comment: You are right. It took 3 secs to finish the computation after setting results.subtitle = FALSE. However, I also lost the pair-wise comparison even though I set pairwise.comparisons = TRUE. Is it possible to keep pairwise comparisons without the results subtitle?

Comment: Noted: https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/issues/397

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will keep the results subtitle for now.

Comment: This is fixed in the development version on GitHub now. You can now show pairwise comparisons without displaying results in the subtitles.